# Keeping a div:hover always in front

Tags: css, html, hover

one question about keeping hovered div's content always visible.

I do have a large Grid made of td's. When hovering over each td i want to display an infobox containing additional data about that td. Current Code:

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrU6m/)

```css
#Grid {
}
.Field {
    border:thin solid black;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.FieldOverview {
    display:none;
}
.Field:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
.Field:hover .FieldOverview {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:thin solid black;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:1;
}
```

My Problem is, that the hover-info-box isn't correctly displayed. I tried to add a z-index to make sure the info box is always shown before the other td's but it doesnt work. I also looked at those Questions, but they didn't quite give me what i needed:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106650/css-menu-keep-parent-hovered-while-focus-on-submenu?lq=1) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340679/css-hover-menu-getting-hovered-menu-item-to-keep-hovered-state-css)

The 2nd Problem i have is that when hovering over a td I want to keep the popping up infobox when the mouse moves into the infobox itself. Currently when moving the mouse in the popping up infobox once the mouse comes over a different td the current infobox is set again to display:none and the infobox of the new td is displayed.

I hope someone of you knows how to accomplish this.

Comment: Can I ask why you are not using a plugin like qTip? Obviously it can be done without it, but you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: try changing the `z-index` from 1 to 9999

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z-index works only on positioned elements (elements with position different from static). You seem tho have added `position: relative` to the `.Field` class so you just need z-index for the hover state:

http://jsfiddle.net/KrU6m/4/

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. Didn't even notice that z-index only works on positioned elements. Learned something again!

Comment: It's a tricky property, actually. You may wish to take a look at this -- http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Be careful about z-index and Internet Explorer thou http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Still one question: Why the .Field:hover state? I mean the one thing i want to be always on top of the others is the .FieldOverview. Not the .Field:hover! Yes your solution does work, but i don't understand why .Field:hover needs z-index:50; Following my understandthing of things i would add z-index:50 to the .FieldOverview cause i want FieldOverview to be the "highest" thing. I am confused.

Comment: Oh, we accidentally messed up and it still works. What's currently happening is that when you hover a `.Field` that hovered element gets a higher z-index and so do its child elements so the `.FieldOverview` inside it will be displayed. You're right -- you can just give `.FieldOverview` `position:relative` and higher z-index and it will function the same way. Both things will have the same effect, actually. Use whichever makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I just added the z-index property.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/KrU6m/2/)

```css
.Field:hover {
    background-color:red;
    z-index: 3000;
}
```